# Android 5.1.1 Developer Options - USB Debugging Not Showing

Tags: android, debugging, usb

i'm working on android version 5.1.1 when i want to show active USB-Debugging  from developer option not showing  for me like the below photo  :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPqBF.png)

Comment: What device is this running on?

Comment: telpo900-android

Comment: Thats a pos device right?

Comment: yes you in right .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device manufacturer seems to have limited the available developer options on that device. Contact the manufacturer to ask them how to enable some form of debugging (USB, WiFi, etc.) and `adb` access.